# How to get a copy of an old Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I was given a Schengen visa in 2009 to France. My passport was expired and replaced and unfortunately lost, after the Schengen visa expiry. Now I want to apply for a Schengen visa to Italy and I need to show my previously issued Schengen visas as supporting documents. Is there any way to ask for a proof or something to show that I have been granted a visa before?

Comment: Do you think you need this additional supporting document? If not, just tell them you had it (and when you did the travel, and the passport number, maybe some ticket reservation). Check if you had on the old travel stuffs some copy of the schengen visa (it was common to make copies of passport and visa). Else you should wait for answer on the more complex procedure.

Comment: Lost is lost. It is a goo iea to take a photo with your cellphone from such documents (and save it somewhere), as that is easier to not lose.